# How to use same EFS Filesystem as two static Persistent Volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, persistent-volumes, volumes

I want to use `same efs` as `two static volumes.`

For that, I have created the below two `PersistentVolume Yamls:`

## Two PVs

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: pv001
spec:
 capacity:
  storage: 5Gi
 volumeMode: Filesystem
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
 csi:
  driver: efs.csi.aws.com
  volumeHandle: fs-0fd788366150f8667.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  volumeAttributes:
   path: "/logs"


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: pv002
spec:
 capacity:
  storage: 5Gi
 volumeMode: Filesystem
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
 csi:
  driver: efs.csi.aws.com
  volumeHandle: fs-0fd788366150f8667.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  volumeAttributes:
   path: "/data"
```

## Two PVCs

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: pvc001
spec:
 resources:
  requests:
   storage: 3Gi
 volumeMode: Filesystem
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: pvc002
spec:
 resources:
  requests:
   storage: 6Gi
 volumeMode: Filesystem
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
```

## Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: test
spec:
 replicas: 3
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: test
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: test
  spec:
   containers:
   - image: nginx
     name: nginx-cont
     volumeMounts:
     - name: logs
       mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
     - name: data
       mountPath: /var/www/html
   volumes:
   - name: logs
     persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc001
   - name: data
     persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc002
```

However, this is throwing below error:

```
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[logs], unattached volumes=[], failed to process volumes=[logs]:
```

Comment: where is your PVC creation and Container with volumeMounts pointing to the PVC and mountPath ? i have a similar scenario without setting the mount path on the PV definition as you have

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I have added those YAMLs

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this a little different. I create the pv:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-0000000000000000e
```

Then I create the pvc:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

And then I use it like this (just as an example):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: upperlower-pod
  labels:
    app: upperlower
spec:
  containers:
    - name: upperall
      image: dm/upperall:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data
  volumes:
    - name: persistent-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: efs-claim
```

Inside the application then something like this:

```
...
# Configure the logger
log_dir = '/data/logs'
log_filename = 'app.log'
log_path = os.path.join(log_dir, log_filename)

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=log_path,
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)

incoming_dir = '/data/incoming'
processed_dir = '/data/processed'
...
```

More info: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/persistent-storage-for-kubernetes/

Comment: Is it possible to use same efs as two PVs? I have updated my question to provide more clarification.

Comment: is it a requirement to use 2 PVs ?

Comment: I tried to use the same EFS as two PVs and was not able to. That's why I went with the single PV and the PVC.